# ANT compiling error 206

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, ant

Our application uses ant to compile. As part of the build file, we've an include that crawls through and grabs all the java files in the application folder and adds them to the command which results in a command like this :

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\bin\javaw.exe, -Xmx512m, -classpath, C:\app\WEB-INF\lib\aspectjtools.jar, org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main, -d, C:\app\WEB-INF\classes, -deprecation, -source, 1.8, -target, 1.8, -classpath, C:\app\WEB-INF\lib\CAMsecurity.jar;C:\app\WEB-INF\lib\CamServices_FileUtilities.jar;...
```

The command is over 70000 characters long. After a few new files were added this week, we started running into this error:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\bin\javaw.exe": CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Java13CommandLauncher.java:58)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:428)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:442)
at org.aspectj.tools.ant.taskdefs.AjcTask.execInOtherVM(AjcTask.java:1473)
... 17 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
... 22 more
```

My current theory is that our command length exceeded the limits set on windows and I was able to find a couple references that seemed to concur. However I'd love to find a way of confirming this and potentially a fix.

Thank you :)

Edit: I forgot to mention, we use AspectJ

Comment: You shouldn't have to build a command. Create a `classpath` in your Ant script and then use it in Ant's `javac` task.

Comment: The error suggests that your command is not what’s too long;  rather, one of the file names given to it is.  If your project isn’t really rooted at `C:\app`, you may be able to resolve the problem by moving the project to a shorter directory like `C:\app`.

Comment: VGR's solution worked but what exactly is the character limit? I've teammates that have the application running under multiple subfolders so I'm assuming that there is a way to modify said max limit.